# Programming an iPad to be a remote gamepad for Windows - Where to start?

Tags: ios, windows, networking, controller, virtual

I want to do something similar to this but for gamepad only http://hipporemote.com/

My end goal is to create a virtual controller for Pop'n Music. If you don't know what it is, here's the video of what it looks like: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMdg41JjzmE

To be clear, by virtual controller, I mean I will design a GUI that reflect each button of the controller I've shown above on the iPad screen. The point is that, you can play an emulator of these music game using iPad as a controller, without having to have the actual controller. So I am not looking for connecting iPad to that actual controller. I'm looking for a way to send input from iPad directly to Windows over some kind of internet connection.

While I know how to write application for iPhone, I'm still newbie regarding network programming. I've looked into the following

- Bluetooth : Not possible, because iOS doesn't support it. Maybe with jailbreak, but I don't feel like going that path.
- Wifi/Bonjour : I've only seen example that connect between iOS and Mac OSX. I haven't seen one working with Windows

So, I'd like some guidance to get started. What do I need to know in order to tackle this project?

Answer (score 3):

- learn to program for micro controllers (i.e. [Arduino](http://www.modern-times-berlin.com))
- learn, how to connect micro controller  and iPad via WIFI (arduino: via [Shields](http://asynclabs.com/store?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=26&category_id=6&vmcchk=1))
- emulate keystrokes on controller, connected to windows machine via serial-over-usb.

for all of this steps you will find plenty of documentation in the net.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my question. I'll update the question to make it clearer.

Comment: I don't think so. first of all I just wanted to show you, that it includes several high complex tasks.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please see it if you have time :)

Comment: Network interfaces are (nowadays) platform independent. there is no TCP/IP/Win or TCP/IP/Mac.